# How can I get this java command to act on each file found by a find command?

Tags: bash, find, java

I have this command inside a Bash shell script, the intention of which is to apply a java command, [htmlcompressor](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/&ei=yTeBT_3gFY6NmQWfpfGPCA&usg=AFQjCNF9bHllqFUpsvsPM77uFR33WY-4vw&sig2=lxkqmLQPjQbgPfMatoy3dg), to each HTML file found in a directory:

```
find $DIR -type f -name '*.html' -exec java -jar $BASEDIR/Upload/htmlcompressor-1.5.3.jar --remove-intertag-spaces {} \;
```

However, while the output at the command line seems to indicate that it is finding each file and doing something with it, it's not actually writing the results to the files.

According to the documentation for htmlcompressor, the usage is this:

> Usage: java -jar htmlcompressor.jar [options] [input]

So there's supposed to be an input file at the named at the end, but I thought the `find` command took care of that. Seems I'm wrong about that, though.

What can I do to make it actually act on the files I find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've provided seems to be correct; you can verify that `java` is being invoked correctly by inserting `echo` into the command:

```
find $DIR -type f -name '*.html' -exec echo java -jar $BASEDIR/Upload/htmlcompressor-1.5.3.jar --remove-intertag-spaces {} \;
```

(assuming a properly POSIX compliant system which has non-builtin versions of shell builtins on the standard `PATH`).

Beyond that, you might want to run one of the resulting commands manually to verify that it is working correctly.

Comment: Oh, apparently I have to set a parameter, `-o`, to specify the output file, otherwise it just runs without saving the changes. So... my bad on not seeing that in the documenation. However, how do I get the `find` command to attach the right input file to the parameter? The command itself needs to be `java -jar htmlcompressor.jar -o output.html input.html`. I want the input and output to be the same, thus: `java -jar htmlcompressor.jar -o same.html same.html`. How do I get the `find` command to do that?

Comment: Will it actually work that way?  (This is worth verifying; some programs, when asked to do that, will destroy their input before they have a chance to read it.)  If it will, simply specifying the {} wherever it's needed will work.

Comment: Yep, that works!